# teradata quartile function (or ANSI SQL)

Tags: teradata, quartile

Is there a simple way to code a SQL quartile function?

Let's say I have a list - column values in a table
(0,0,0,1,1,4,5,7,8,25,100,100,101,260,360,370}

What's the good way to generate a resultset a-la:

```
select 'Q1', quartile(1,col_name) from table_name
union
select 'Q2', quartile(2,col_name) from table_name
union
select 'Q3', quartile(3,col_name) from table_name
union
select 'Q4', quartile(4,col_name) from table_name
;
```

I haven't found anything usable for this regard so far.

Comment: Can you show your expected output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand why you want Q4 :) There's no need to use the percentile_cont() function for that, you can get it using max().

This code might help you.

```
select      'q1' as q
            , percentile_cont(0.25) within group (order by col) as q_val
from        table
union
select      'q2' as q
            , percentile_cont(0.5) within group (order by col) as q_val
from        table
union
select      'q3' as q
            , percentile_cont(0.75) within group (order by col) as q_val
from        table;
```

Comment: What is the Teradata version you're using? Doesn't seem this exists in TD14.

Comment: Bart's answer is correct for TD14.10+, before you have to rewrite it, see http://developer.teradata.com/blog/dnoeth/2011/06/missing-functions-percentile-disc-percentile-cont-median In fact this should be more efficient in 14.10, too, because each `percentile_cont` is calculated individually.